# How to count the number of possible paths through a network with 3 particular states in R

Tags: r

I made a function that will draw a network in R. There are 2 types of networks:

1. One with 2 possible sates (0 and 1)
2. Another with 3 possible sates (0, 1, and 2)

par(mfrow=c(1,1))

```
get.fit.land <- function(nb.g = 3, # Number of loci
                         alleles.state = FALSE, 
                         main = "Fitness landscape",
                         draw.network = TRUE, 
                         add.geno.txt = TRUE) {
  # par(mfrow = c(1,1))
  # Empty list 
  l.gen = list()
  
  # Nb of different genotypic states (if genotypes 0, 1, 2, should be 3^number; if alleles, 0 or 1, should be 2^number)
  (nb.states = 3^nb.g )
  # Nb of different paths 
  nb.paths = factorial(nb.g)
  
  if (nb.g > 10) {
    stop("Too many combinations for computation!")
  }
  
  # Make a list of loci with either 0:1 (alleles) or 0:2 (genotypes)
  if (alleles.state) {
    for (i in 1:(nb.g)) {
      l.gen[[i]] <- 0:1
    }
    
  } else {
    for (i in 1:(nb.g)) {
      l.gen[[i]] <- 0:2
    }
    
  }  
  # Make a combination of all possible alleles/gnenotype
  comb.gen = expand.grid(l.gen)
  comb.gen$sort = 1:nrow(comb.gen)
  comb.gen$sq.space = apply(comb.gen[,-which(names(comb.gen)=="sort")], 
                            MARGIN = 1, 
                            FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))
  
  # calculate the Hamming distance
  comb.gen$nb.mut = apply(X = comb.gen[,-which(names(comb.gen) %in% c("sort","sq.space"))], 
                          MARGIN = 1, 
                          FUN = sum)
  
  # Reorder the data  
  comb.gen.od = (comb.gen[order(comb.gen$nb.mut),])
  
  # Empty plot 
  plot(0, type = "n", #asp = 1, 
       ylab = "",
       xlab = "",
       yaxt="n",
       xaxt="n",
       main = main, 
       xlim = c(-.50,length(table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut))-1+0.5), 
       ylim = c(-(max(table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut))-1)/1.5, 
                (max(table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut))-1)/1.5));abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
  # fit.sq.space from genotype.check.R 
  comb.gen.od = comb.gen.od[order(comb.gen.od$sort),]
  rec.tmp = NULL
  
# For segments needs rec.tmp (should be cleaned here.... )
  # NOTE THAT THE NETWORK CONNECT *ALL* POINTS REGARDLESS OF THE ORDER OF MUTATIONS...
  for (j in 1:length((table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)))) {
    # Get a sequence of numbers (y) that will spread the points symmetrically from the x axis
    tmp = seq(-(table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)[j]-1)/2, 
              (table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)[j]-1)/2, 
              length.out = table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)[j])
    # Record the number
    rec.tmp = c(rec.tmp, list(tmp))
  }
  if (draw.network) {
    for (k in 1:(length(rec.tmp)-1)) {
      rec.tmp[[k]]
      
      segments(x0 = k-1, x1 = k, 
               y0 = rep(rec.tmp[[k]], each = length(rec.tmp[[k+1]])), 
               y1 = rec.tmp[[k+1]], 
               col = scales::alpha("red", .4))
    } # End for k
  } # end if 
  # plot --------------------------------------------------------------------
  unik.vals = unique(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)
  # Add all combinations 
  for (j in 1:length((table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)))) {
    # Get a sequence of numbers (y) that will spread the points symmetrically from the x axis
    tmp = seq(-(table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)[j]-1)/2, 
              (table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)[j]-1)/2, 
              length.out = table(comb.gen.od$nb.mut)[j])
    # Record the number
    rec.tmp = c(rec.tmp, list(tmp))
    # Add the points 
    points(x = rep(j-1, length(tmp)), 
           y = tmp, # Set the y position of all the points 
           pch = 19, 
           cex = 1, 
           col = scales::alpha("black", .5))
    
    if(add.geno.txt){
      # comb.gen.od[order(comb.gen.od$nb.mut),"sq.space"]
      text(x = rep(j-1, length(tmp)), 
           y = tmp, 
           pos = 2,
           labels = sort(comb.gen.od[comb.gen.od$nb.mut %in% unik.vals[j], "sq.space"]))
    } # End if add text for genotypes 
  } # end loop j 
  
} # end function 

get.fit.land(nb.g = 3, alleles.state = T, draw.network = F)  
get.fit.land(nb.g = 3, alleles.state = F, draw.network = F)
```

Here are the figures (I added the red paths with the rule 'add' +1 to any position on a node on the network to get to the next position)

For 2 possible sates (0 and 1)
[image]

For 3 possible sates (0, 1, and 2)

[image]

I want to compute (and draw the paths) the number of possible paths (with a rule saying that we can only 'add' +1 to any position on the network: so 000 can become 001, 010, 100; but 101, can't become 011 because it would mean decreasing 101 to 001 and then increasing 1 in the second position to give 011, which is not allowed from that rule.) Simply, I'm looking for drawing a Hamming graph.

For 2 possible sates (0 and 1), the number of paths is simple: it's the number of combinations of number factorial. So a network with 3 'slots' is 3! so 6 unique paths from left to right.

For 3 possible sates (0, 1, and 2), I have no idea on how to calculate that. How could this be done (and draw the paths) on the network? In my code, there is an argument that will draw the segments between ALL the paths (but not respecting the rule that I stated earlier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me apologize that instead of modifying your function I started from scratch, I found it easier. So either use my approach or adopt from it anything you find useful. It can be used for any combination of number of loci and alleles, as long as it is computationally feasible, of course.

```r
nb.g <- 3          # number of loci
n.states <- 3      # number of states
# all possible combinations
combs <- do.call(expand.grid, replicate(nb.g, seq_len(n.states)-1, simplify=F))
# reorder them for plotting
combs <- combs[order(rowSums(combs), 
                     colSums(t(combs)*n.states^(rev(seq_len(nb.g))))), ]

# build a data frame representing genotypes
genotypes <- as.data.frame(combs)
names(genotypes) <- paste0('l', seq_len(nb.g))
genotypes$label <- rownames(genotypes) <- 
  apply(genotypes, 1, paste, collapse='')
# x and y coordinates for plotting
genotypes$x <- rowSums(combs)
genotypes$y <- unlist(tapply(genotypes$x, genotypes$x, \(x) 
                             seq_along(x) - length(x)/2 - .5))
```

Now that we have the genotypes and information to be used later on, we can find the *+1* connections. Here I just added 1, column by column, and then removed target genotypes that do not exist (e.g. those containing 3 in the case of three states):

```r
# find all adjacent genotypes (including non-existing ones)
from.to <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nb.g), \(i) 
                                 cbind(combs, combs + (col(combs)==i))))
# remove targets with impossible states (>= n.states)
from.to <- from.to[!apply(from.to, 1, \(row) any(row > n.states-1)), ]
# create data frame with edges connecting pairs of genotypes
edges <- apply(from.to, 1, paste, collapse='')
edges <- data.frame(from=substring(edges, 1, nb.g), 
                    to=substring(edges, nb.g+1))
# add coordinates of edge points
edges <- cbind(edges, 
               genotypes[edges$from, c('x', 'y')],
               genotypes[edges$to, c('x', 'y')])
# rename new columns to 'x.from', 'y.from', ...
names(edges)[3:6] <- paste0(names(edges)[3:6], '.', 
                            rep(c('from', 'to'), each=2))
```

And now we're ready to plot:

```r
frame()
plot.window(xlim=range(genotypes$x) + .5*c(-1, 1), ylim=range(genotypes$y))
abline(h=0, lty=2)
with(edges, segments(x.from, y.from, x.to, y.to, col='red'))
points(genotypes[, c('x', 'y')], pch=19, col=gray(.5))
text(genotypes[, c('x', 'y')], labels=genotypes$label, pos=2)
box()
```

[image: network of genotypes]

To find the number of all possible paths I find it easiest to use *igraph*. So first we create a graph representation from the edge list and then use `all_simple_paths()` to find all paths between the two extreme points of the genotype network.

```r
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(edges[, c('from', 'to')]), directed=T)
paths <- all_simple_paths(g, genotypes$label[1], to=tail(genotypes$label, 1))
length(paths)
# 90
```

Comment: Genius! And your code is much faster when we increase the number of 'alleles'! Thanks for your generous time!

Comment: You're welcome, I like such kind of problems! ;-)